# Saving data when sending it via post method

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form, example:

```
<form method="post" action="some external URL">
    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="session_id" />
    <input type="hidden" id="val1" name="val1"  />
    <input type="hidden" id="val2" name="val2" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

I need to save this data into mySQL before sending it into "some external url" - let's say that my "saving to database" script is on "script/save" url. How can I transfer my data there before sending it throught this form?

**EDIT**

It would be nice, when my form will only be sent to "some external url" when the "script/save" gives POSITIVE RESPONSE. 
Could you help me with that too?

Comment: You might want to write an internal script that accepts the post data, processes it for your DB, and then cURL a post over to the external URL.

Comment: Yeah - but isn't some ajax solution nicer?

Comment: Ajax could be nicer, but you could run into issues with the same origin policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey just use an ajax call onsubmit then submit the form when the ajax call is done

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSomething()
    {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open('GET', 'yourscript.php, true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
                var response = xmlHttp.responseText;
                // response is what you return from the script
                if(response == 1){
                    alert('works');
                    form[0].submit;
                }else{
                    alert('fails');
                }
            }else{
                alert('fails');
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="external-url" method="post" onsubmit="doSomething();">
        <input type="text" name="blah" id="blah">
        <input type="submit" value="save">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Database access is handled at the server, which is what your form is transferring to.  Therefore, in order to do this, re-route your form to a different script on the server; this script will write to the database and then call "some external URL".

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use ajax to send the data to your url during the onsubmit event of your form. The following code might work for you.

```
$("form").submit(function(){        
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({url: 'script/save', type: 'post'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of posting your form to the external URL, post it to an internal script:

```
<?php
// Process your $_POST here and get all the stuff you need to process your SQL statements.

// Then, POST to the external URL:

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "your external URL");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```